# How can you order columns in HTML output when using ConvertTo-HTML in Powershell?

Tags: html, sorting, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I use ConvertTo-HTML to convert a list of objects into a table. The only problem is that I cannot define the order of the columns in that table. I want a specific property (hostname) for all of the objects to be the first column in the table. Is there any way to do this?

**Example Code:**

```
function Create-MyObject {
    param(
        $name
    )

    $object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        "Name" = $name
        "Prop1" = Get-Property1 $name
        "Prop2" = Get-Property2 $name
        "Prop3" = Get-Property3 $name
    }

    return $object
}

$myarray = @()

foreach($value in $list)
{
    $myarray += Create-MyObject -name $value
}

Add-Content -Value $(ConvertTo-HTML $myarray | Out-String) -Path "C:\Temp\output.html"
```

Comment: Can we see the code?  Objects created from regular hash table don't maintain the property order. Typically you fix that with an ordered hash table, or doing a Select-Object to re-build them in the right order after they're created.

Comment: @mjolinor Although it's not the exact code I'm using, this is the gist of it. When I open the HTML, it might show the columns in the order `Prop3`,`Prop1`,`Name`,`Prop2` (it might also be alphabetical, but I don't have the actual code to look at at the moment). I want `Name` to be first in the list of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution that modifies the function to create the object from an ordered hash table so that the order is maintained.  This requires V3 or better.

```
function Create-MyObject {
    param(
        $name
    )

    $object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property [ordered]@{
        "Name" = $name
        "Prop1" = Get-Property1 $name
        "Prop2" = Get-Property2 $name
        "Prop3" = Get-Property3 $name
    }

    return $object
}

 $myarray = @()

    foreach($value in $list)
    {
        $myarray += Create-MyObject -name $value
    }

Add-Content -Value $(ConvertTo-HTML $myarray | Out-String) -Path "C:\Temp\output.html"
```

Heres's another solution using Select-Object in the main script to reorder the properties before it's converted. This will work on V2 or better:

```
$myarray = @()

foreach($value in $list)
{
    $myarray += Create-MyObject -name $value
}

Add-Content -Value $(ConvertTo-HTML $myarray | Out-String) -Path "C:\Temp\output.html"



function Create-MyObject {
    param(
        $name
    )

    $object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        "Name" = $name
        "Prop1" = Get-Property1 $name
        "Prop2" = Get-Property2 $name
        "Prop3" = Get-Property3 $name
    }

    return $object
}

$myarray = @()

foreach($value in $list)
{
    $myarray += Create-MyObject -name $value
}

$myarray = $myarray | select Name,Prop1,Prop2,Prop3

Add-Content -Value $(ConvertTo-HTML $myarray | Out-String) -Path "C:\Temp\output.html"
```